# Using Start-Job on script

Tags: powershell, start-job

Using a script in PowerShell to recursivly pass through all folders on multiple NAS boxes to display every folder with its full path in an `Out-File`. 
Using the `Get-FolderEntry` script I found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-FolderEntry-List-all-bce0ff43#content).

Since I have multiple NAS boxes with more then 260 chars in the filename/pathlength I figured I'd use multithreading to speed the process up.

**Code:**

```cs
. C:\Users\mdevogea\Downloads\Get-FolderEntry.ps1
# list with the servers
$Computers = Get-Content C:\Users\mdevogea\Desktop\servers.txt

# scriptblock calling on get-FolderEntry
$sb = {
    param ($Computer, $fname)
    C:\Users\mdevogea\Downloads\Get-FolderEntry.ps1 -Path $Computer |
        fl | Out-File -Append -Width 1000 -FilePath $fname
}

foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{
    $name = $Computer.Replace("\", "")
    $fname = $("C:\Users\mdevogea\Desktop\" + $name + ".txt")
    #Get-FolderEntry -Path $Computer | fl | Out-File -Append -Width 1000 $fname

    $res = Start-Job $sb -ArgumentList $Computer, $fname
}

# Wait for all jobs
Get-Job
while(Get-Job -State "Running")
{
    Write-Host "Running..."
    Start-Sleep 2
}
# Get all job results
Get-Job | Receive-Job | Out-GridView
```

So far:

1. I either get empty files with the correct naming of the file.
2. I get the correct named file with the code of `Get-FolderEntry` in it.
3. I get errors depend on what I pass along to the scriptblock.

In short, it's probably stupid but don't see it.

Comment: Inside the scriptblock first dot-source the *script* `Get-FolderEntry.ps1`, then invoke the *function* `Get-FolderEntry`. If that doesn't help show the errors you're getting.

Comment: I presume you mean like this:

$sb = {. C:\Users\mdevogea\Downloads\Get-FolderEntry.ps1 param ($Computer, $fname) C:\Users\mdevogea\Downloads\Get-FolderEntry.ps1 -Path $Computer | fl | Out-File -Append -Width 1000 -FilePath $fname
}


if so then this is the error:

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

Comment: The `Param()` statement must be first. Then dot-source. And you're *still* running the *script* instead of the *function*.

Comment: sry about that, i'm relatively new to powershell.
so the correct scriptblock would be: 

$sb = {param ($Computer, $fname) . C:\Users\mdevogea\Downloads\Get-FolderEntry.ps1 Get-FolderEntry -Path $Computer| fl | Out-File -Append -Width 1000 -FilePath $fname}


if i run it like that, it runs without errors, but my files are empty (so without the full paths to all subdirectories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it eventually myself after some trial and error:

```
. C:\Users\mdevogea\Downloads\Get-FolderEntry.ps1
# list with the servers
$Computers = Get-Content C:\Users\mdevogea\Desktop\servers.txt

# scriptblock calling on get-FolderEntry
$sb = {
    Param ($Computer, $fname)
    . C:\Users\mdevogea\Downloads\Get-FolderEntry.ps1 
    (Get-FolderEntry -Path $Computer | fl | Out-File -Append -Width 1000 -FilePath $fname)
}

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    $name = $Computer.Replace("\", "")
    $fname = $("C:\Users\mdevogea\Desktop\" + $name + ".txt")
    $res = Start-Job $sb -ArgumentList $Computer, $fname
}

# Wait for all jobs
Get-Job
while (Get-Job -State "Running")
{
    Write-Host "Running..."
    Start-Sleep 2
}
# Get all job results
Get-Job | Receive-Job | Out-GridView
```

Thanks a lot Ansgar for pointing my in the right direction!